# osascript button position in dialog box

Tags: applescript

Wanting a larger space between Yes and No buttons within the dialog box

```
 osascript -e 'display dialog "Choose a button ..." buttons {"Yes", "No"} default button "No" giving up after 5'
```

This positions both buttons side by side but I want a larger space between the buttons ..

Any ideas ?

Comment: The positions follow Apple's Human Interface Guidelines. You can't modify them in AppleScript, unless you actually write an AppleScript application that includes NIBs with custom-made interface elements.

Answer (score -1):

Ok in that case I've ended up putting a dummy button between both

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'display dialog "Choose Button ..." buttons {"YES", "", "NO"} with icon file ((path to home folder as text) & "Path:to:picture.png")'
```